# C++ template techniques for straightening out recursion?

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, design-patterns

Assume I have a function that has a naturally occurring recursion, but I want to avoid to do recursion for any number of reasons. Do there exist any good ways to apply templates in C++ to systematically reshape the code execution to avoid the possible hazards of recursion?

---

An example, we can assume `T1`, `T2` are some types and `start()`, `end()` some arbitrary functions taking arguments and returning things of the respective types:

```
T2 recursion(T1 a1){
  T1 l1 = start(a1);
  if( recurse_condition(a1,l1) )
     T2 l2 = recursion(l1);
  else return final(a1,l1);
  return end(l2);
}
```

So if I understand tail-recursion right it would be possible to do only if the `end()` function did nothing, but we assume here that it might do something.

---

(I am not extremely frequently on this site so feel free to redirect me if question is more suitable somewhere else.)

Comment: Why should it be done with templates?

Comment: To try to answer your question would require a huge list of proofs...

Comment: @rex: because i am curious if it would be possible to do with templates.

Comment: If you can write your code in a form that is [tail-recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), then the compiler will not use recursion. Search for "tail recursion" to find out more about it.

Comment: It's very difficult to respond to your question. The answer greatly depend (I suppose) from the exact problem, the reasons because you want to avoid the recursion and what has to do the function. Can you show as a recursive example to see if it's possible to derecursivize it?

Comment: Just as a good answer would provide some examples, a good question should do the same. You could throw a template in anywhere you like, but to avoid recursion one first has to select some way to avoid the recursion (depends on the situation) and then decide if a template can help.

Comment: ... and obviously you intend C++11 or newer (so variadic templates), not old C++98, isn't it?

Comment: @max66 I would be OK with either of them. Feel free to use your favourite. I edited the question to hopefully make it easier to answer.

Comment: about your `start()`/`end()` example... what interrupt the recursion?

Comment: ow, of course! how sloppy of me, will fix.

Answer (score 1):

Given your example (a little corrected)

```
template <typename T2, typename T1>
T2 recursion(T1 a1){
  T1 l1 = start(a1);
  if( recurse_condition(a1,l1) )
     T2 l2 = recursion<T2>(l1);
  else return final(a1,l1);
  return end(l2);
}
```

I suppose you can avoid the recursion with something like (also C++98)

```
template <typename T2, typename T1>
T2 noRecursion (T1 a1)
 {
   std::size_t cnt ( 0U ); // counter: how many time is
                           // executed `start()`

   T1 l1 ( a1 );

   do
    {
      a1 = l1;
      l1 = start(a1);

      ++cnt;
    }
   while ( recurse_condition(a1, l1) );

   T2 l2 ( final(a1, l1) );

   // exec end() one time less than start()
   while ( --cnt ) // shorter than for (auto ui = 1U ; ui < cnt ; ++ui)
      l2 = end(l2);

   return l2;
 }
```

In this case, the template aspect (`T1` and `T2`) are independent from the recursion/not recursion aspect: is useful in the not recursive function is if useful in the recursive version.

Comment: yes something like that seems to me like it could work, but recursion has two template arguments.

Comment: @mathreadler - the second one (`T1`) should be deduced from the input argument (`a1`, or `l1` from the internal point of view); it's the reason because I've written `template <typename T2, typename T1>` instead of `template <typename T1, typename T2>`: writing first the deducible type (`T1`) you are forced to explicit both arguments (calling `T2 l2 = recursion<T1, T2>(l1);`); leaving last `T1` you can deduce it through `l1` and you're forced to explicit only `T2`.